# can we make the background image fixed on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using the css given below for fixing a background image of body.

```
 body { 
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    background-image:url(../images/main-bg.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover; 
    -moz-background-size: cover; 
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;   
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

It is working correct on all other browsers but in IE if I press cntrl + scroll the image will get repeated
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use:

```
body { 
    background-color: #963F23;
    background-image: url('/docs/background/bgtheme/bg.jpg'); 
    background-position: center top;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {  
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:12px; 
    background:url(../images/main-bg.jpg) fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;  
    -moz-background-size: cover;  
    -o-background-size: cover;  
    background-size: cover;   
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0; 
}
```